# enum vs separate table for storing roles?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I have to implement a role system in my app for authorization. We have around 5 kind of roles in our system.

To maintain these roles we have 2 options,

**Alternative #1**

1.Create an enum in rails Role model,

`enum role: {super_admin: 1, translator: 2, approver: 3, sales_admin: 4, marketing_admin: 5, guest: 6}`

2.In the Roles table , now we will have `ID user_id role_id`

**Alternative #2**

1.Create 2 models `Role and Role_User`.

Role table will only contain `ID | role_name` and Role_User will contain `ID | user_id | role_id`

Which should be preferred?

Comment: I don't think there is some specific rule for this. It's more of your estimation for specific system and your personal preference. Personally I prefer separate table over enum anytime

Comment: Storing on the database means the data is available to anyone with SQL (reports, standalone SQL queries etc) but I prefer the enum from performance point of view.  Alternative 3 is to do both, which covers all bases but adds extra work.

Comment: I suggest to go with second approach as it will give you the flexibility to add new roles without changing and deploying your application code. Also it is always good to keep the entities clear and separate.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to go for second approach as if in future there is any possibility of additional role there will be no burden for you to create that additional role. With first approach you have to edit your enum for additional roles which you might want to add in future

Answer (score 2):

It depends how baked into your code the roles are. Some systems have a very rigid concept of "admin" or "moderator" or "user" and introducing roles that don't fit those slots can cause chaos. In those cases they're better off left hard-coded. You might have a table simply to convert the internal name into a label, something especially important when translation's involved. "admin" becomes "Administrator", or whatever that means in the other languages your system employs.

If you've got a system that's a lot more adaptable, where the roles table can define arbitrary permissions, then it makes a lot more sense. You can create custom roles that will work within the structure of the system because the system was deliberately engineered for it. A "role" in this cases is just a set of permissions.

Answer (score -1):

An added benefit of the separate table is that users can have multiple roles, if that is something your system requires. Also, storing the different roles in the database should be better for enforcing database-level data integrity, i.e. you can't add nonexistent roles to users.

If you do end up using a separate table for roles and a join table, be sure to add proper indexing to the join table.

Other than that, it really depends on the context and use case. If the system is simple enough, nothing wrong with going the enum way.

Comment: No reason multiple roles can't be hard-coded